# Creating a gallery page in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a gallery page in laravel 4, where the gallery page displays the categories and if you click on a category then a list of all the items that belong to that category is displayed. I'm having an issue with mine. When I click on my category I get a blank page. So I was wondering if anyone here knows of a laravel 4 tutorial to do what I need. But just in case you want to see my code here it is.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@content');
Route::get('/{title}', array('as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'HomeController@test'));
```

my pcategory.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 gallery">
        <ul class="pics">
            @foreach($pages->pcategory as $port)
                <?php
                    $portImage = getImagesArray($port->image)
                ?>
                <li>
                    @if(!empty($portImage))
                        @foreach($portImage as $portImg)
                            {{ HTML::linkRoute('test', $port->title, $port->id)}}
                        @endforeach
                    @endif

                </li>
            @endforeach
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

my HomeController.php

```
public function test($title){
    echo "public function test";
}
```

Comment: Please, post generated URL to Route?

Answer (score 0):

The third paramater of linkRoute function should be array. Try:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('test', $port->title, ['title' => $port->id] )}}
```

Maybe another error - controller function *test* expects a title, but View sends a id.

Comment: I get sent to a blank page instead of the test function in the HomeController